# what is the format of stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0 model on hugging face?

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, stable-diffusion

I am confused by the format of the [stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0](https://huggingface.co/stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0) model. Is it a pytorch model or is it an onnx model?

I tested `ORTStableDiffusionXLPipeline.from_pretrained(model_id, export=True, provider="ROCMExecutionProvider",)` vs `ORTStableDiffusionXLPipeline.from_pretrained(model_id, export=False, provider="ROCMExecutionProvider",)`, it seems there is no difference for setting `export` to True vs False. Based on my understanding, if the model is already in onnx format, then this export argument will play no role here; but if it is in pytorch format, it should give me error message if I set export to False. Can anyone share any thoughts on this?

Thank you!